# Cannot Pull JSON From Webpage Kotlin Compose

Tags: json, kotlin, url, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to connect to a foreign API to load images of Pokemon for my Pokemon Go stats app.

I tried the following code(As well as a very wide variety of other solutions such as retrofit or java in kotlin)

```
var imagesURL = URL("https://archives.bulbagarden.net/w/api.php?action=query&prop=imageinfo&format=json&iiprop=url&titles=File:HOME655.png|File:HOME654.png")
imagesURL.readText()
```

I expect to have the program correctly give me the text on the webpage, but my program instantly crashes every time I run this. Could anybody help?

Comment: Please post the crash logs/stacktrace so people can see what the "crash" is.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that you include [internet permission](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#INTERNET) in your app's [manifest](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro).

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Android by default don't allow you to do networking on [main thread](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads#Threads), so try using a [coroutine](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines):

```kotlin
GlobalScope.launch {
    val imagesURL = URL("https://archives.bulbagarden.net/w/api.php?action=query&prop=imageinfo&format=json&iiprop=url&titles=File:HOME655.png|File:HOME654.png")
    val responseData = imagesURL.readText()
}
```

I also [wouldn't recommend you to launch this in a GlobalScope](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines/coroutines-best-practices#global-scope), instead, use something [lifecycle aware](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines) like [LifecycleScope](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#lifecyclescope).

When using GlobalScope, if your image is still loading and user navigates off the current screen, image will still try to load in the background, but you don't need it anymore.

However, when using something like LifecycleScope, if image doesn't load and user navigates off the screen, image request will be canceled.

I can't be anymore specific because you didn't provide enough informations about your issue. Please post at least error message.

Comment: I would post an error message but it doesn't give me one even in debug!  The app just randomly crashes. I'll try this out though, thanks for the help!